# Как загрузиться с CD ROM ?

Tags: настройки, железо

У знакомых есть старенький Pentium III (если надо, распишу железо подробнее). Там были проблемы с загрузкой и я поставил в BIOS : **Load optimized defaults**. Настройки по умолчанию. Стало загружаться нормально. (Точнее, первым делом поставил "Load Fail-Safe Defaults", а потом уже "Optimized...", но это, наверное, неважно.)

Там раньше стояло первое загрузочное устройство -- CD ROM, стало Floppy. Второе устройство -- HDD. Ставлю опять **First boot device: CD ROM**Ан нет! Грузится только с жёсткого диска!

**Вопрос: что ж ему, собаке, ещё надобно? :-)**

**P.S.** Никакие физические подключения не менялись. До этого (т.е. сброса настроек на "по умолчанию") первой шла загрузка с CD ROM'a.

Comment: BIOS такой: CMOS Setup Utility - Copyright(c) 1984-2000 **Award Software**

Comment: А если флопи вообще нафиг физически отключить?

Comment: у меня случалось подобное только в случае плохого CD диска, либо, уже достаточно изношенного привода. Я слышал что привод разгоняется, но толку было ноль. А после повторной перезагрузки - БАХ! И загрузилось всё.

Comment: попробуйте для проверки отключить жёсткий диск

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, верно ли определяется биосом привод CD-ROM. С наибольшей вероятностью, дело в этом.

Если же нет: проверьте, сохраняются ли настройки очередности загрузки. Попробуйте во время POST-тестирования нажимать F8, F9 или F12 (в зависимости от материнской платы, подробнее в мануале) для открытия меню очередности загрузки.